# Running docker container with google chrome profile

Tags: python, docker, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-profile

I collect data from one site, using python, selenium and chromedriver. I use my google chrome profile to bypass the captcha. There was a need to run my script in a docker container. I can't launch chrome with my profile from docker.
*My Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.8
# Adding trusting keys to apt for repositories
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -

# Adding Google Chrome to the repositories
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'

# Updating apt to see and install Google Chrome
RUN apt-get -y update

# Magic happens
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# Installing Unzip
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip

# Download the Chrome Driver
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip

# Unzip the Chrome Driver into /usr/local/bin directory
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

# Set display port as an environment variable
ENV DISPLAY=:99

WORKDIR /app
COPY /src/yamarket_parsing_container.py .
COPY /requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "yamarket_parsing_container.py"]
```

*my code*

```
PATH_TO_CHROME_PROFILE = r"user-data-dir=../root/.config/google-chrome/User Data/"
PROFILE_DIR_NAME = '--profile-directory=Default'


def init_browser(p_profile_path, p_profile_dir_name):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument(p_profile_path)
    options.add_argument(p_profile_dir_name)
    options.add_argument('--headless=new')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

m_browser = init_browser(PATH_TO_CHROME_PROFILE, PROFILE_DIR_NAME)
```

*run command*

```
D:\Shared\parsing_yandex_market>docker run -ti -v "C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data":/root/.config/google-chrome img
```

*error*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yamarket_parsing_container.py", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "yamarket_parsing_container.py", line 90, in main
    m_browser = init_browser(PATH_TO_CHROME_PROFILE, PROFILE_DIR_NAME)
  File "yamarket_parsing_container.py", line 28, in init_browser
    return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Could not read in devtools port number
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55832cd86243 <unknown>
#1 0x55832cb4a7a6 <unknown>
#2 0x55832cb76ed0 <unknown>
#3 0x55832cb72a51 <unknown>
#4 0x55832cb6f49b <unknown>
#5 0x55832cbb12a7 <unknown>
#6 0x55832cbb08cf <unknown>
#7 0x55832cba7e53 <unknown>
#8 0x55832cb7a9ea <unknown>
#9 0x55832cb7bb2e <unknown>
#10 0x55832cddad5e <unknown>
#11 0x55832cddea80 <unknown>
#12 0x55832cdc08b0 <unknown>
#13 0x55832cddfb63 <unknown>
#14 0x55832cdb1f75 <unknown>
#15 0x55832ce02998 <unknown>
#16 0x55832ce02b27 <unknown>
#17 0x55832ce1dc23 <unknown>
#18 0x7f74762c1ea7 start_thread
```

Has anyone encountered such a problem? I would be grateful for any advice.

I have tried placing the "User data" directory in different locations, but without success. Chromedriver is not initializing.

Comment: have you verified that the chrome and chromedriver versions installed on the container are compatible? is it possible the version installed in your container doesn't support the new headless mode yet?  The only reference I found with that exact error message was that it meant a failure in Chrome startup. https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/JS9yLCTfewk

Comment: Versions chrome and chromedriver are matched. I receive error, when I tried set chrome profile directory and name directory.

Comment: This seems to most likely be a file permissions issue, or more specifically, a [bind-propagation issue](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/16173/bind-mount-from-host-not-appearing-in-docker-container-when-using-compose), as the Chrome User Profile directory has multiple sub-directories.   The [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation) says it only applies to Linux hosts, but that would seem to also include WSL.